Xcode 15.1 crashes when Runner is clicked
Xcode 15.1 keeps crashing when Runner.xcworkspace is open for project version 2.11 but when i opened the Runner.xcworkspace for previous project version 2.10, xcode didn't crash. so the issue is with new project version 2.11.
i need solution to this. thanks
